# R: fastest way to set up matrix of integrals?

Tags: r, matrix, integration

I have a tree-parameter function `f(x, y, z)`, and two limits `L, U`.

Given a vector `v`, I want to set up a matrix with element `M[i, j] = INTEGRAL( f(x, v[i], v[j]) )`, where the integrals limits go from `x = L` to `x = U`.

So the problem has two elements:

1. We need to be able to calculate the integrals. I don't care how this is done, as long as its FAST and reasonably accurate. Fast, fast, fast!! What's the fastest way?
2. We need to set up the matrix `M[i, j]`. What's the fastest way?

Please don't make this an issue of "dO yOu WaNt GauSsIan QuaDraTure oR SimPsoNs ruLe?". I don't **care**. Speed is the only thing relevant here. Whatevers faster, I'll take it, as long as the integrals are at least accurate up to 1-2 digits or something.

Comment: On the face of it, this could be done using the R stats base function `integrate` within double `for` loops .  Efficiency could really only be addressed if we could see an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: check out my answer if it is what you want

Answer (score 2):

A potentially fastest solution is given as below

```
library(pracma)
M <- matrix(0,nrow = length(v),ncol = length(v))
p <- sapply(seq(length(v)-1), function(k) integral(f,v[k],v[k+1]))
u <- unlist(sapply(rev(seq_along(p)), function(k) cumsum(tail(p,k))))
M[lower.tri(M)] <- u
M <- t(M-t(M))
```

---

## Regarding the two elements requested by OP

- I guess `integral` from package `pracma` is fast enough
- To build the matrix `M`, I did not used nested `for` loop. The idea is explained at the bottom lines, which I believe speeds up the computation remarkably

---

## Benchmark

I wrote down some of the possible solutions and you can compare their performance (my "fastest" solution is in `method1()`).

```
set.seed(1)
library(pracma)

# dummy data: function f and vector v
f <- function(x) x**3 + cos(x**2)
v <- rnorm(500)

# my "fastest" solution
method1 <- function() {
  m1 <- matrix(0,nrow = length(v),ncol = length(v))
  p <- sapply(seq(length(v)-1), function(k) integral(f,v[k],v[k+1]))
  u <- unlist(sapply(rev(seq_along(p)), function(k) cumsum(tail(p,k))))
  m1[lower.tri(m1)] <- u
  t(m1-t(m1))
}

# faster than brute-force solution
method2 <- function() {
  m2 <- matrix(0,nrow = length(v),ncol = length(v))
  for (i in 1:(length(v)-1)) {
    for (j in i:length(v)) {
      m2[i,j] <- integral(f,v[i],v[j])
    }
  }
  m2 + t(m2)
}

# slowest, brute-force solution
method3 <- function() {
  m3 <- matrix(0,nrow = length(v),ncol = length(v))
  for (i in 1:length(v)) {
    for (j in 1:length(v)) {
      m3[i,j] <- integral(f,v[i],v[j])
    }
  }
  m3
}

# timing for compare
system.time(method1())
system.time(method2())
system.time(method3())
```

such that

```
> system.time(method1())
   user  system elapsed 
   0.17    0.01    0.19 

> system.time(method2())
   user  system elapsed 
  25.72    0.07   25.81 

> system.time(method3())
   user  system elapsed 
  41.84    0.03   41.89
```

---

## Principle

The idea in `method1()` is that, you only need to calculate the integrals over intervals consisting of adjacent points in `v`. Note that the integral properties:

- `integral(f,v[i],v[j])` is equal to `sum(integral(f,v[i],v[i+1]) + integral(f,v[i+1],v[i+1]) + ... + integral(f,v[j-1],v[j]))`
- `integral(f,v[j],v[i])` is equal to `-integral(f,v[i],v[j])`

In this sense, given `n <- length(v)`, you only need to run integral operations (which is rather computational expensive compared to matrix transpose or vector cumulative summation) `n-1` times (far less than `choose(n,2)` times in `method2()` or `n**2` times in `method3()`, particularly when `n` is large).

Comment: I interpret the problem a bit differently.  `f(x,y,z)` has three independent parameters.  The integral is over `x` between the fixed limits L and U.  An example of such a function would be `cos(y*x)*cos(z*x)` with the integration limits `0` to `n*pi`. v is a vector of frequencies.  I don't think your `method1` would apply with this interpretation.

Comment: @WaltS Yes, maybe you interpretation is right! OP ddin't show any example for problem description. If the case is as you described, then nested `for` loop might be inevitable